# (Ruby on Rails) Passing two params args to search method? Raising "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive consulted other related questions on here and found them helpful, except now in my controller I have the lines:

```
if params[:query].present? && params[:queryb].present?
  @model = Model.search(params[:query], params[:queryb])
```

where the second of those lines raises an "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error?

How else should I be structuring this query? ThankS!

Comment: What does your search method in Model look like?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn im using the searchkick gem

Comment: I think `search` just takes a string, right? Try `@model = Model.search("#{params[:query]} #{params[:queryb]}")` to pass both queries in a single string.

Comment: what is the `::search`?